# How to wrap an HOC component twice

Tags: reactjs

I have a class component in a reactjs app, that I want it to use router and translation.

```
interface CommonHeaderProps extends RouteComponentProps<any> {
}

class CommonHeader extends React.Component<CommonHeaderProps> {  

  render() {


    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({

})

const mapDispatchToProps = {};

export default withRouter(connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(CommonHeader));
```

I would like this component to have be

`withRouter()(CommonHeader)`
and 
`withTranslation()(CommonHeader)`

but doing this do not work

```
export default withTranslation()(withRouter(connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(CommonHeader)));
```

I tried

```
const Component = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CommonHeader)

export default compose<CommonHeader>(
 withTranslation,
 withRouter,
)(Component)
```

But then I get the following error when I try to call the component :

> JSX element type 'CommonHeader' does not have any construct or call
>   signatures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming** `withRouter()(CommonHeader)` & `withTranslation()(CommonHeader)` both work, it looks like you still need call the two HOCs inside `compose`

```
export default compose(
  withTranslation(), // note the `()`
  withRouter(),      // note the `()`
)(Component)
```

You can also move `connect` inside `compose`

```
export default compose(
  withTranslation(), 
  withRouter(), 
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps,)
)(CommonHeader)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Indivisually they do works.

There is no error in the commonHeader file, but when I call it from App.tsx I still have the same `SX element type 'CommonHeader' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

Comment: Wanna put up a Code sandbox? It's hard to offer guidance, since there's a lot of missing context.

Comment: Can you remove the `<CommonHeader>` type casting and see if that works?

Comment: will try to make in a bit, and ping you when is done thank you for your time

Comment: in my case correct option was: 
     export default compose(
       withTranslation(), 
       withRouter, 
       connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps,)
     )(CommonHeader)